# steam fatal error "steam needs to be online to update, but was set to offline movies."

Tags: updates, offline, steam

I tried re-installing  it but it simply keeps giving me this error in a little window. When I close it, an identical error pops up some 3 seconds later without any new provocation.

Answer (score 9):

I have installed `libnss-resolve:i386` by running the following command.

```
apt-get install libnss-resolve:i386
```

And now it works for me.

Comment: How did you figure this out?

Answer (score 8):

Make sure steam isn't running at all in `~/.steam/`.

1. Delete `~/.steam/steam.pid`
2. Edit `~/.steam/registry.vdf` line 29 from "Offline" "1" to "Offline" "0"

[Source](http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/882966056380564675/)

Comment: In my case, "Offline" was already set to "0" but Steam kept starting in Offline mode. Luckily, step 1 was enough to fix the issue.

Comment: what is ~/.steam/steam.pid , is it some kind of directory where can i  Find it

Comment: I am having this problem and your solution didn't work because the file ~/.steam/registry.vdf didn't exist

Answer (score 7):

I am running Ubuntu 17.04 and the other answers didn't solve it. I had force an entry on `/etc/hosts` for `media.steampowered.com`.

So, first get the IP with

```
ping media.steampowered.com
# returns 200.143.247.11 for me
```

then add that to `/etc/hosts`, like this:

```
200.143.247.11 media.steampowered.com
```

And it should work as expected.

Comment: You sir, are a legend!

Comment: Also, I needed to install `libnss-resolve:i386` as mentioned in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/steam/+bug/1651025

Answer (score 6):

This solved it for me

```
sudo apt-get install xfonts-75dpi xfonts-100dpi
```

Try it! if first time dont work, restart!

Comment: a combination of this and deleting ~/.steam/steam.pid did the trick for me. Also, ~/.steam/registry.vdf didn't exist

Comment: I am having the same problem and this solution did not work for me nor did the above one.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution that worked for me with (gnome 3) Ubuntu 17.04
Install the package `libnss-resolve:i386`
(`sudo apt-get install libnss-resolve:i386`)

Answer (score 1):

After following all solutions on this page, steam would still fail on first start after install.

Steam's cdn has stale files. In order to fix this, you must bypass all cdn's and directly download from the origin servers.

In order to do that, I've added the following to `/etc/hosts`:

```
208.64.200.30 media.steampowered.com
208.64.200.30 media1.steampowered.com
208.64.200.30 media2.steampowered.com
208.64.200.30 media3.steampowered.com
208.64.200.30 media4.steampowered.com
```

The `208.64.200.30` ip correponds to `cdn-01-origin.steampowered.com`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was not enough space on the disk. At least 250MB are required. After freeing space, the install process started correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above solutions, and while I was finally able to update the client,and log in, the problem I was facing. Actually being able to play a game (content server unreachable) was not possible.

I was able to solve the problem by adding

207.173.177.11 steam1.steampowered.com
To /etc/hosts file.
And then launching steam from command line.

Hope this helps someone!